# Cannot find value email of undefined -- angular4 and .net core

Tags: angular, .net-core

A complete beginner in .net core and angular here; having a few difficulties. I have a registration form with couple of text boxes in it. Trying to write the angular4 code that will get the values provided by user and save them to database. Right now, I have the console error - cannot read value 'email' of undefined
which looks like it is unable to read value from the input text boxes.

My html block -

```
    <form #regForm="ngForm" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="simple-article" #email type="text" name="email" value="" ([ngModel])="model.email" placeholder="Your email" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:9px">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="simple-article" type="password" #password value="" ([ngModel])="model.password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="checkbox-entry">
                <input type="checkbox" #agree ([ngModel])="model.agree" required name="agree" />
                <span>I agree to the <u><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></u></span>
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn-success" (click)="onRegClicked(email.value, password.value, agree.checked)">
                Register
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My angular code -

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

    model: { email: 'NONE', password: 'NONE', agree: false };
    validEmail: boolean = true;
    errors: any;
    isRequesting: boolean;
    submitted: boolean = false;

    constructor(private router: Router, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private confService: ConfigService, private common: CommonFunctionsService, private appService: AppService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    onRegClicked(email: string, password: string, agree: boolean) {
        if (this.common.hasValue(email) && this.common.hasValue(password)) {
            if (!agree) {
                alert('You must agree to register!');
                return;
            }
            let user = <UserRegistration>{
                email: email,
                password: password
            };

            this.registerUser({ value: user, valid: true });

        }
        else {
            alert('Please fill out all the fields!');
            return;
        }
    }

    registerUser({ value, valid }: { value: UserRegistration, valid: boolean }) {

        this.validEmail = true;
        this.submitted = true;
        this.isRequesting = true;
        this.errors = '';

        if (valid) {
            this.appService.register(value.email, value.password, 0)
                .take(1)
                .finally(() => this.isRequesting = false)
                .subscribe(
                (result: any) => {
                    if (result.success) {
                        //this.appService.Ulogin(value.email, value.password);
                        this.validEmail = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.validEmail = false;
                    }
                },
                (errors: any) => this.errors = errors
                );

        }
    }
}
```

and commonFunctionsService is -

```
export class CommonFunctionsService {

    constructor() { }

    hasValue(str: string) {
        return str !== undefined && str !== null && str !== '';
    }

    copyObjectFromTo(obj1: any, obj2: any) {
        Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => {
            obj2[key] = obj1[key];
        });
    }

    trimIfGreaterThan(str: string, maxLength: number) {
        if (str.length > maxLength)
            return str.substring(0, maxLength) + '..';
        else
            return str;
    }

    getEmailUserName(email: string) {
        return email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@'));
    }

    getUtcNow(): Date {
        var now = new Date();
        return new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
    }
}
```

Where is the error in the above code that I wrote? Initially I had novalidate in the form but I removed that too. Still no luck. onRegClicked is the function that is supposed to pick the values supplied to the text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the `model.email` in the html

```
 <a class="btn-success" (click)="onRegClicked(model.email, model.password, agree.checked)">
```

Comment: hi again, have changed the code, not quite there still. Right now, I have the html as - 

<a class="btn-success" (click)="onRegClicked()">Register</a>

And the angular code as -
onRegClicked() {
        if (this.model.email.length != 0 && this.model.password.length!=0) {
            if (!this.model.agree) {
                alert('You must agree to register!');
                return;
            }
            ........
             
still not there, same error! 
is there something else wrong with the html?
thanks,

Comment: solved this by using (document.getElementById("....") as HtmlInputElement).value; the values are being picked fine. Although, this defeats the original purpose of using the model class. However have to stick to this only, until I am able to pinpoint the reason why my original code didn't function as expected. Thanks anyway,

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to shorten the method signature to:

```
onRegClicked() {
    ...
```

and reference the variables instead with

```
this.model.email
this.model.password
this.model.agree
```

which would leave the HTML cleaner:

```
<a class="btn-success" (click)="onRegClicked()">
```

---

Otherwise, fix your issue by adding `model.` before each parameter in the HTML:

```
<a class="btn-success" (click)="onRegClicked(model.email, model.password, model.agree)">
```